# Como fazer um submit enviando dados preenchidos no form para um email?

Tags: javascript, html, envio-de-email

```html
<div id="mainDiv">
    <div id="marca">
        <img class="imagens" src="media/img/titulo.png" alt="Titulo">
    </div>

    <div id="anaMaria">
        <img class="imagens" src="media/img/fundoCadastroDois.png" alt="FundoCadastroDois">
    </div>

    <div id="cadastro">
        <p>....</p>
        <form id="contatoForm" method="post" action="mailto:teste@mail.com">
            <input class="cells" type="text" name="nome" placeholder="nome">
            <input class="cells" type="text" email="email" placeholder="email">
            <button type="submit" value="click" id="enviar"></button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Implementei este código acima, mas assim que faço o submit do formulário, abre o meu próprio email e com os dados preenchidos como se eu fosse mandar um novo email. O que eu quero é que o usuário preencha com nome e email nos campos e esses dados vão para minha caixa de entrada. Procurei soluções mas a maioria utiliza o mesmo que estou fazendo ou com href, que não resolve o problema. Sei que é simples mas preciso de uma coisa simples para finalizar.

Comment: Para enviar email precisa de um servidor SMTP. Qual a linguem que você está utilizando?

Comment: possível duplicata de [Como enviar e-mails somente com o básico de HTML5](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/213/como-enviar-e-mails-somente-com-o-basico-de-html5)

Comment: Acho que está havendo um erro de interpretação na pergunta do Guilherme, me parece (pelo código e teor do texto), que quer preencher o email e não envia-lo em si, de forma que o form dele usa mailto. Corrija-me se eu estiver errado.

Comment: Me parece que ele quer sim enviar, mas vamos aguardar o autor esclarecer (nota: como interpretei diferente, rejeitei sua sugestão de edição, @GabrielGartz).

Comment: @bfavaretto Se você estiver certo eu te ajudo clicando no fechar e guardo a minha resposta pra alguém que tenha essa dúvida e ela seja útil.

Comment: Uma coisa é fato, independente de qual linguagem você está utilizando, está faltando o `name` na `input` de email...

Comment: Pessoal, realmente nao fui claro na minha pergunta, o que eu quero é que o usuário preencha com nome e email nos campos e esses dados vão para minha caixa de entreda. Mas pelas respostas que alguns de vocês me deram, não tem como fazer isso sem um servidor.

Comment: Obrigado por esclaracer, Guilherme. Então me parece mesmo uma duplicata.

Comment: @GabrielGartz É uma duplicata, mas eu não excluiria sua resposta.

Comment: @bfavaretto eu fiz o que prometi assim que li o comentário do rapaz. Você estava certo, a má interpretação foi minha.

Comment: Eu tenho dúvidas se realmente é um duplicata. Pode ser mesmo, está parecendo, mas ambas tem respostas interessantes. Elas conseguem ser mescladas? É um bom parâmetro para saber se é duplicata. Mesmo que o merge não seja feito.

Comment: @bigown Eu acredito que possam ser mescladas, considerando as respostas atuais. O único argumento contra considerar duplicata é que a outra pergunta *exige* que não se use nada server-side, e essa não (e usar algo server-site talvez seja a resposta que o autor está procurando aqui).

Comment: Você usa qual linguagem? Java, ASP, PHP? Algum framework com elas tipo Struts ou JSF (caso Java que é minha linha de conhecimento)?

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi usarei Java com struts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

De acordo com seu comentário eu usaria esse form direcionando ele via POST para uma action do Struts e nessa action utilizaria [Velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/) para montar o template HTML do que será o e-mail.

Depois, para de fato enviar o e-mail, você tem que ter informações de login, senha, caminho POP ou IMAP do servidor bem como a porta para enviar utilizando a própria API de e-mail do *Java EE*. Eu particularmente uso [Apache Commons Mail](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/) que internamente usa a API do Java EE, mas simplifica para nós desenvolvedores como fazê-lo.

Answer (score 5):

O navegador não envia email, porém é possível criar um link que já chama o cliente de email do usuário, com endereço, assunto e conteúdo formatado para o email poder ser enviado.

Segue exemplo:

```
<a href="mailto:algum@email.com?Subject=Aqui%20vai%20o%20assunto&Body=E%20aqui%20o%20corpo">preparar email</a>
```

Esta mesma técnica pode sim ser utilizada junto do seu formulário, exemplo:

```
<form id="contatoForm" method="get" action="mailto:teste@mail.com" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" name="Subject" value="Meu assunto">
    <input type="hidden" name="Body" value="">
    <input class="cells" type="text" name="nome" placeholder="nome">
    <input class="cells" type="text" name="email" placeholder="email">
    <button type="submit" value="click" id="enviar"></button>
</form>
```

Você vai precisar de um pequeno Javascript pra formatar seu texto.

**Javascript nativo:**

```
document.getElementById('contatoForm').addEventListener('submit', function () {
    var nome = this.querySelector('input[name=nome]'), nome = nome.value;
    var email = this.querySelector('input[name=email]'), email = email.value;
    var texto = 'Olá destinatário, \nMeu nome é '+ nome +' e meu email é '+ email;
    this.querySelector('input[name=Body]').setAttribute('value', texto);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/EB9k5/1/)

**Versão em jQuery:**

```
$('#contatoForm').on('submit', function () {
    var nome = $(this).find('input[name=nome]'), nome = nome.val();
    var email = $(this).find('input[name=email]'), email = email.val();
    var texto = 'Olá destinatário, \nMeu nome é '+ nome +' e meu email é '+ email;
    $(this).find('input[name=Body]').attr('value', texto);
});
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/EB9k5/2/)

Considerações:

- A action do form deve ser GET (e não POST, alguns browsers vão aceitar POST, não todos);
- Adicionei o target no form para ter compatibilidade com clientes de email embutidos no browser;
- Seu input do email estava com email=email e é name="email", poderia causar um erro na hora de selecionar o campo;
- Não esqueça que o DOM deve ter sido carregado para vc poder adicionar o listener para evento do formulário;

Comment: Bom, considerei a resposta do @Gabriel Gartz a correta, pois o que eu queria nao da pra ser feito sem hospedar minha pagina em um servidor, entao ajustei minha pagina a fazer o que ele me deu como resposta a cima! Obrigado a todos pela ajuda!

Comment: @GuilhermeVianna bom saber que minha resposta te ajudou, foi nostálgico escrever essa resposta, tive que lembrar como se formatava email com uri, algo que vem dos primórdios dos browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Navegadores não enviam email.
O seu código é o mais perto que você vai chegar usando apenas o navegador.

Você não consegue enviar email apenas com HTML & JavaScript -- em aplicações Web, você só consegue enviar emails de forma segura no lado servidor.

Existem [maneiras de enviar email sem ter um servidor fazendo requisição AJAX para um serviço externo](https://medium.com/design-startups/b53319616782) como [este](https://mandrill.com), mas não são recomendáveis porque são inseguras (é fácil alguém mandar email no seu nome), com alto potencial para abuso.

Comment: Entendi, vou hospedar ele...fazendo isso você sabe me dizer como fazer isso mais simples possivel @elias?

Comment: @GuilhermeVianna Então, acho que o jeito mais simple é enviar com o Gmail mesmo, pra não precisar configurar um servidor SMTP. Se você for usar PHP no servidor, pode [seguir esse tutorial](http://blog.caixadesolucoes.com.br/post/enviando-emails-com-phpmailer-e-gmail).

Answer (score -2):

O [Formspree](https://formspree.io/) é um site que possui uma API que pode ser integrada diretamente ao seu código HTML sem a necessidade de uma linguagem back-end para fazer o envio dos dados do formulário para o seu email.

Sua forma de uso é bem simples:

1. Primeiro você se registrar no site colocando o email cujo vai ser enviado o fomulário da sua aplicação.
2. Depois de você se cadastra corretamente no site [Formspree](https://formspree.io/) é só pega o URL gerado pelo site e integrar na sua tag `<form>` no atributo `action`. Ao seu fomulário ser enviado pelo usuário, você vai receber um email com os dados enviados no respectivo email que você cadastrou no site. Todos os input devem conter o atributo `name` preenchido para identificação quando o fomulário for enviado para seu email.

Exemplo:

```
<form action="https://formspree.io/f/{form_id}" method="post">
  <label for="email">Your Email</label>
  <input name="Email" id="email" type="email">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

obs: Lembrado que é obrigatório o uso do method="post".

No próprio site tem uma aba chamada "Submissions" cujo você pode ver todos os emails que foram mandados para você [Imagem](https://ibb.co/DCc7Nd5).

Answer (score -3):

Seguindo sua sugestão consegui fazer o que eu queria. No campo "email" eu coloquei para que não aparecesse o email para onde seria enviado o formulario.
O email é redirecionado direto pro email colocado no campo "value"

Segue código como ficou, e conforme pode verificar no código, eu acrescentei novas labels e funcionou direitinho:

```
  <form
            action="https://formspree.io/f/{form_id}"
            method="POST"
            >
            <label>
                Esse e-mail será encaminhado direto para a empresa:
                <th type="email" name="email" readonly=“true” value="email@provedor.com">
            </label>

            <br>
            <hr>
        
                   

            <label for="nome">Seu nome</label>
            <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" >
            <br>
            <hr>
            <label for="contato">Motivo do contato</label>
            <input type="text" id="contato" name="contato" >
            <br>
            <hr>
            <label for="descricao">Mensagem</label>
            <textarea name="descricao" id="descricao" ></textarea>

            <hr>
            
            <!-- your other form fields go here -->
            <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
```