# Envio de formulário sem PHP

Tags: javascript, html5

Boa Tarde Desenvolvi um site de html5 e css3 e assim agora estou com um "probleminha" tenho que fazer um formulário nesse site com informações básicas como nome telefone email e assunto e a mensagem e isso devera ser enviada pro meu email quando a pessoal enviar o formulário gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira de fazer isso sem o uso do php

Segue o meu codigo com o MAILTO:

```
<form id="main-contact-form" action="MAILTO:felipe.henrique1446@gmail.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
                <div class="row  wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome" required="required">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required="required">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Assunto" required="required">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="4" placeholder="Escreva sua Mensagem" required="required"></textarea>
                </div>                        
                <div class="form-group">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn-submit">Enviar</button>
                </div>
              </form>
```

Comment: Veja se ajuda,(talvez seja duplicata de) [Como fazer um submit enviando dados preenchidos no form para um email?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4475/91) e 
[Como enviar emails utilizando JavaScript?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8701/91)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara se você criar um formulário e enviar para "mailto:"

Olha o exemplo do W3Schools

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_mail

Lembrando que não há garantias se vai funcionar em todos os browsers.

Comment: interesante amigo mais veja assim e so eu colocar o meu email no caso nesse trecho aqui :action="MAILTO:someone@example.com" method="post" enctype="text/plain" logo apos MAILTO: e pronto ?

Comment: Isso mesmo, simples assim.

Comment: caraca eu nao botei fe sauhsauhsa mais olha eu fiz aquii e nao funcionou vou postar um trecho do meu codigo ai voce da uma olhadinha

Comment: Prontinho esta la no post

Answer (score 1):

Gostaria de salientar que isso é uma medida paliativa pois ao usar o comando "mailto:" você apenas estará indicando ao navegador/OS que quer abrir algo no caso o cliente de email.

Porém em muitos casos - como o meu - a pessoa não possui ou não usa um programa de email configurado então fica mais complicado a pessoa te encaminhar alguma mensagem.

Sem contar que você não pode metrificar o usuário como por exemplo navegador que ele usou, IP do usuário e coisas assim (sei que estou pensando de forma complexa mas é possível).

Bem se esse formulário não for de risco e etc. eu recomendaria usar esses serviços grátis de encaminhando de formulário, onde você copia a URL fornecida e coloca no seu formulário, só pesquisar no Goole.

Comment: O Ideal então e usar PHPMailer então não é