# Como enviar um email a partir de um formulario de um site em HTML?

Tags: html, envio-de-email

Tenho um template de um site em HTML que possui um formulário para e-mail,como faço pra captar os dados preenchidos no formulário e enviá-los pro meu e-mail?

```
<h3>Email</h3>
<form method="post" action="#">
    <div class="row uniform">
        <div class="6u 12u(3)">
            <input type="text" Nome="Nome" id="Nome" value="" placeholder="Nome" />
        </div>
        <div class="6u 12u(3)">
            <input type="email" Nome="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="Email" />
        </div>
        <div class="6u 12u(3)">
            <input type="text" Nome="Assunto" id="Assunto" value="" placeholder="Assunto" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row uniform">

        <div class="6u 12u(2)">
            <input type="checkbox" id="human" Nome="human" checked>
            <label for="human">Sou humano</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row uniform">
        <div class="12u">
            <textarea Nome="message" id="message" placeholder="Digite sua mensagem" rows="6"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row uniform">
        <div class="12u">
            <ul class="actions">
                <li><input type="submit" value="Enviar" /></li>
                <li><input type="reset" value="Limpar" class="alt" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Você precisará usar uma linguagem de programação. Um exemplo é o `PHP`.
Além de ter que trocar algumas tags dos `inputs` que estão como "Nome=" e tem que ser "name=" Veja nesse link como enviar email com PHP: http://www.marcelotorresweb.com/formulario-de-contato-em-php/

Comment: Está usando alguma linguagem server side?

Comment: Se for sem o auxílio de linguagens server-side, acabo de ver que é duplicata desta aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/213/ - Se for com PHP, é desta aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23602/

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como enviar e-mails somente com o básico de HTML5](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/213/como-enviar-e-mails-somente-com-o-b%c3%a1sico-de-html5)

Answer (score 3):

Sem usar uma linguagem *server side*, o jeito é esse:

```
<form method="post" action="mailto:destinatario@example.com">
```

Mas isso é uma solução um tanto problemática, pois depende de o usuário ter um cliente de email configurado corretamente (só funciona para webmail em condições um tanto especiais, e não só se o *browser* estiver preparado para isso).

Com o suporte de uma linguagem *server side*, tudo muda. Aí você tem que especificar qual é a linguagem em questão.

**EDIT:** pesquisando melhor, parece duplicata desta:

> [Como enviar e-mails somente com o básico de HTML5](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/213/)

Se for com PHP, é duplicata desta:

> [Como enviar e-mail com PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/23602/)