# Tenho um site e gostaria de receber mensagens do site no meu email, como faço?

Tags: html

como faço para receber mensagens do usuários do meu site no meu email?

```
  <form class="form mb-5" method="POST" action="https://formspree.io/hg_20111@outlook.com" style="color: #fff">
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="inputNome">Nome</label>
          <input type="name" class="form-control" id="inputnome" required placeholder="Nome">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
          <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" required placeholder="Email">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-10">
        <label for="inputEndereco">Endereço se atendimento a domicílio</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEndereco" placeholder="Rua, Bairro">
        </div>
      </div>          

      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-8">
          <label for="inputCity" >Cidade</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputCity" placeholder="Itapecerica da Serra" required>
        </div>
      </div>  
      <div class="form-row">

        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <label for="inputState">Serviços</label>
          <select id="inputState" class="form-control">
            <option selected>Mão,Pé,Mão e Pé...</option>
            <option>Mão</option>
            <option>Pé</option>
            <option>Pé e Mão</option>
            <option>Maquiagem</option>
            <option>Escova</option>
            <option>Dia de noiva</option>
            <option>Design Unhas</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <label for="inputData">Horário</label>
          <input type="date" class="form-control" id="inputData">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <label for="inputZip">Horário</label>
          <input type="time" class="form-control" id="inputZip">
        </div>
      </div>       

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Agendar</button>

  </form>
```

Comment: Hugo sua pergunta está muito vaga, do jeito que perguntou uma resposta como *"Enviando um email"* seria aceitável. Explique melhor o seu problema ou dúvida

Comment: Abra seu browser e digite no Google "PHPMailer", boa pesquisa.

Comment: @RicardoPontual kkkk é verdade.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como enviar um email a partir de um formulario de um site em HTML?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/122238/como-enviar-um-email-a-partir-de-um-formulario-de-um-site-em-html)

Comment: Não existe mágica, sem um backend: script ou aplicação no servidor; ou alguma api de terceiros. Você vai depender de algum cliente de e-mails do usuário para realizar essa atividade.