# como fazer para enviar os dados do formulário para meu email com html e javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, email, envio-de-email

Olá, gostaria de saber como envio os dados preenchidos do formulário para o meu email utilizado html e javascript.
Desde ja agradeço.

Comment: Já existe a mesma solicitação -> https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/213/como-enviar-e-mails-somente-com-o-b%C3%A1sico-de-html5

Comment: Só com HTML e JavaScript vc não consegue. Tem que usar alguma linguagem de servidor, como PHP.