# Enviar e-mail sem finalizar o formulário

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Eu tenho um formulário em html em passo a passo, que quando eu clicar no botão "próximo" eu preciso que envie os dados preenchidos por e-mail porém sem finalizar o formulário, como posso fazer isso, é em php?

Comment: Coloque o que você já tentou na sua peegunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode usar `AJAX`, que é uma mistura de `PHP` e `JQUERY`.

Eis um exemplo

```
$(".enviar_email").click(function(){ //botão para enviar
    var nome = $(this).attr("data-nome "); //variaveis
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id"); //variaveis
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", //Pode usar, POST ou GET. Prefiro por POST
        url: "ajax/enviar_email.php", //ficheiro de envio de email com o código php nele
        data: "nome ="+nome +"&id="+id, //envio de variaveis pelo que você definiu no TYPE
        success: function(e){ //e equivale ao que retorna dele.
            console.log(e);
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: eu fazendo isso, consigo fazer o email ser enviado sem resetar o form né?

Comment: Sim, experimente

Comment: Você poderia me fazer um exemplo funcionando? Não consegui aplicar

Comment: Como posso fazer? Não sei o seu código, poste algum `HTML`

Answer (score 0):

Para enviar um email vai ser preciso o uso de php como já respondido nesta outra pergunta aqui: [Como enviar e-mails somente com o básico de HTML5](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/213/como-enviar-e-mails-somente-com-o-b%C3%A1sico-de-html5)

O que você quer dizer com "Sem finalizar o formulário"? Se quiser que a pessoa possa voltar mais tarde para preencher o restante do formulário sem ter de inserir novamente as outras informações você pode usar html5 e o localstorage pra isso, armazenando as informações dentro do navegador do usuario. Segue link com explicações: https://www.devmedia.com.br/trabalhando-com-html5-local-storage-e-json/29045

Se quiser que estas informações possam ser acessadas de outro navegador ou de outro computador, vai ter de armazena-las em um banco de dados mesmo.

Comment: Eu preciso que ao clicar no botão "próximo" o que foi preenchido seja enviado porém sem finalizar o formulário

Comment: Então você só vai ter de usar php e ajax para enviar um email quando clicar em próximo. Assim ele vai executar a função de enviar o email sem finalizar o formulário. Link que pode ser util: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_intro.asp

Comment: Na verdade o que ele está um ajax para fazer o post parcial do forumlário sem fazer o submit do form principal.

Comment: Isso é exatamente isso que vou precisar que faça