# Como envio um e-mail sem finalizar o formulário

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Eu queria saber se tem como eu fazer um disparo de e-mail sem fazer a chamada do action do meu form, pois ele tem 4 passos, e no processo do 1º para o 2º passo eu quero enviar por e-mail os campos que foram preenchidos, sem finalizar meu formulário, pois se eu utilizo o submit chamando o action ele encerra meu formulário e volta para o 1º passo, ao invés de passar para o 2º passo. Eu só preciso que ao clicar no botão ele pegue os dados digitados e envie por e-mail sem me dar nenhum retorno de enviado, já tentei tudo que eu conheço

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Enviar e-mail sem finalizar o formulário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/297882/enviar-e-mail-sem-finalizar-o-formul%c3%a1rio)

Comment: Ja tentou usar jquery?

Comment: Eu já tentei ajax, mas não consegui, ao clicar no botão ele finaliza meu formulário, e eu só preciso que ao clicar no botão ele só dispare os input para um e-mail sem finalizar o form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para cada passo crie uma div

- primeira div `<div class="form1-group" id="passo1">`
- segunda div `<div class="form2-group" id="passo2">`
- terceira div `<div class="form3-group" id="passo3">`
- quarta div `<div class="form4-group" id="passo4">`

**CSS**

```
//oculta as divs
#passo2,#passo3,#passo4{
    display:none;
}
input{
    width:220px;
}
```

**Exemplo de formulário**

```
<form id="regForm" action="recebe-do-form.php" method="post">
    <div class="form1-group" id="passo1">
      <p><input minlength="5" type="text" class="form-control" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="Nome Completo*" /></p>
      <p><input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email Válido*" /></p>
      <p><input type="text" class="form-control" id="celular" name="celular" placeholder="Telefone" /></p>
      <p><input type="text" class="form-control" id="sobre" name="sobre" placeholder="Como ficou sabendo sobre festas?" /></p>
      <button type="button" id="form1" onclick="validate(id)" /> Próximo</button>
    </div>

    <div class="form2-group" id="passo2">
      <input type="text" name="idade" value="" id="idade" placeholder="Idade" />
      <br />
      <input type="text" name="nascimento" id="nascimento" value="" placeholder="Data nascimento" />
      <br />
      <button type="button" id="form2" onclick="validate(id)" /> Próximo</button>

   </div>

   <div class="form3-group" id="passo3">
      <input type="text" name="estado" value="" id="estado" placeholder="Estado" />
      <br />
      <input type="text" name="cidade" value="" id="cidade" placeholder="Cidade" />
      <br />
      <button type="button" id="form3" onclick="validate(id)" /> Próximo</button>

   </div>

   <div class="form4-group" id="passo4">
      <input type="text" name="cargo" value="" id="cargo" placeholder="Cargo" />
      <br />
      <input type="text" name="empresa" value="" id="empresa" placeholder="Empresa" />
      <br />

      <button type="button" id="form4" onclick="validate(id)" /> Enviar</button>
   </div>

</form>
```

> Cada grupo de `div` contém um `button` que chama a função `validate(id)` passando o valor do `id`
>
> A função `validate(id)`, de acordo com o `id` passado executa as ações desejadas, tais como, validar nome, email e o que mais desejar. Observe os comentários no código.

```
function validate(id){
    /*
    Recupera o id do button clicado e
    verifica se o nome contém pelo menos 5 caracteres
    valida email
    e se estiverem ok, executa o ajax para enviar o email
    pode validar os outros campos dessa div (celular e sobre) se assim o desejar
    */
    if (id=="form1"){
        var strNome = document.getElementById("nome").value;
        if (strNome.length<5){
           $( '#nome' ).css( "border", "2px solid #e74c3c" );
           $( '#nome' ).val( "" );
           $( '#nome' ).attr("placeholder", "Minimo de 5 caracteres!");
           $( '#nome' ).focus();
           return false;
        }else{
           $( '#nome' ).css( "border", "2px solid green" );
        }

        var filter = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
        if(!filter.test(document.getElementById("email").value)){
           $( '#email' ).css( "border", "2px solid #e74c3c" );
           $( '#email' ).focus();
           return false;
        }

        //valores do primeiro passo para passar via email
        var nome = $("#nome").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var celular = $("#celular").val();
        var sobre = $("#sobre").val();

        var dataString = {"nome":nome,"email":email,"celular":celular,"sobre":sobre };

            $.ajax({
                url: 'enviarMail.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: dataString,
                success: function(data){
                    //$("#resultado").html("Dados enviados com sucesso "+data);
                }
            });//ajax 
    }

     //neste estou validando a data de nascimento
     if (id=="form2"){
         var strNascimento = document.getElementById("nascimento").value;
         var patternData = /^[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}$/;
            if(!patternData.test(strNascimento)){
                $( '#nascimento' ).val( "" );
                $( '#nascimento' ).attr("placeholder", "dd/mm/yyyy");
                $( '#nascimento' ).css( "border", "2px solid #e74c3c" );
                return false;
            }
    }

    //aqui envia o formulário
    if (id=="form4"){
        $("#regForm").submit();
    }

    /*
    recupera o ultimo caractere da string id, soma 1,
    esconde todas as divs e mostra a div seguinte a atual.
    */
    var res = id.charAt(id.length-1);
    res=parseInt(res)+1;
    //esconde todas
    $('div[id^="passo"]').hide();
    //mostra a proxima
    $('#passo'+res).show();


}
```

**enviarMail.php**

```
/******* CODIGO EMAIL *******/

/* Uma dica para envio de emails
Baixe os arquivos  PHPMailerAutoload.php - class.smtp.php -  class.phpmailer.php
em github - https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/5.2-stable
Crie uma pasta  PHPMailer-master no mesmo diretório da sua aplicação PHP e 
publique os arquivos baixados nesta pasta (PHPMailer-master).
*/


$nome = $_POST['nome'];

$email = $_POST['email'];

$celular = $_POST['celular'];

$sobre = $_POST['sobre'];

//email Destinatario
$emailDest = "nome@dominio.com";

$email = Trim(str_replace("'","",$email));


require_once 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.dominio.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = 'username@dominio.com';
$mail->Password = 'senha';

//$mail->SMTPSecure = false; //Diz que nao tem tls/ssl
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';  
//$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = false; //Diz que nao tem tls/ssl

//$mail->SMTPDebug = 2; //Mostra os bugs

//E-mail remetente
$mail->From = $email;

//Nome do remetente
$mail->FromName = $nome;

//Assunto da mensagem
$mail->Subject = "teste mail";

//Corpo da mensagem
$mail->Body = "Celular ".$celular." - Mensagem ".$sobre;

//Corpo da mensagem em texto
//$mail->AltBody = 'Conteudo do e-mail em texto';


//Destinatario 
$mail->AddAddress ($emailDest);

$mail->Send();
```

Comment: Muito bom seu exemplo! Eu consegui resolver meu problema recentemente com a utilização de ajax, muito obrigado pela ajuda!!